# How to debug my C++ BMI calculator program?

Tags: c++, c++11, debugging

I've only recently learnt C++. I had a school project for making a BMI calculator. Unfortunately it is showing up errors beyond my scope of understanding. I'm not sure if I should use a different data type for my height and weight variables - should these by double?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float bmi_calc(int height, int weight){
    float bmi_user = weight / height * height;
    return bmi_user;
}

int main()
{
    int weight_user;
    int height_user();

    cout << "Enter your weight in kilograms";
    cin >> weight_user;

    cout << "Enter your height in meters";
    cin >> height_user;

    cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi_calc(height_user, weight_user);
}
```

Comment: `int height_user();`? You should remove the parentheses. Also `weight / height * height` is equivalent to `weight`. Make sure you add parentheses around `height * height`.

Comment: `int` is not going to be a good unit for a height in metres as it will only allow 0, 1, or 2 metres...

Comment: If you have *"errors beyond my scope of understanding"* you should probably include them as part of your question and explain why they are unclear

Comment: According to your question title, you should read: [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float bmi_calc(float height, float weight) {
    return weight / (height * height);
}

int main()
{
    float weight_user;
    float height_user;

    cout << "Enter your weight in kilograms ";
    cin >> weight_user;

    cout << "Enter your height in meters ";
    cin >> height_user;

    cout << "Your BMI is " << bmi_calc(height_user, weight_user);

    return 0;
}
```

since your height is given in meters you need a float, since a int can only be used for whole numbers. also use proper parenthesis to get the formula right :)